# get Array element facebook Api javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am already spending hours, and I think it is a small problem. Actually I can not find any solutions yet that fit for me (like make a new method to handle arrays in javascript, because I have to use the prebuilt functions of the Facebook Api).

I want to collect all the data from a Facebook account, but some of this data are in Arrays located, such as Likes, Feed, Favorite_teams, etc.

How can I display all this array data in a single line (I only need the text itself, and so not the ID of a post, or creation date).

For example for likes I make the following code in Javascript:

```
for (i = 0; i < response.likes.data.length; i++){
                document.getElementById('likes').innerHTML = response.likes.data[i].name;
                }
```

But when I print the Div of course it shows the last element of the array. How can I show them all?

Comment: Try adding `+`, `document.getElementById('likes').innerHTML += response.likes.data[i].name;`.

Comment: each time when it loops it change the inner value thats why u r getting last value so just add`+` before `=` sign

Comment: *document.getElementById('likes').innerHTML = response.likes.data.map(e => e.name).join(', ');*

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan since you just posted this as comment, i hope you don´t mind if i add it to my answer. it´s a pretty cool solution :)

Comment: @luschn No problem. Cool with me .... :D

Answer (score 2):

```
var responseData = '';
for (i = 0; i < response.likes.data.length; i++){
    responseData += response.likes.data[i].name;
}
document.getElementById('likes').innerHTML = responseData;
```

Do not change innerHTML in a loop, and make sure to "add", not "overwrite".

...or even better if there are many items:

```
var responseData = '',
    likeData = response.likes.data;
for (i = 0, count = likeData.length; i < count; i++){
    responseData += likeData[i].name;
}
document.getElementById('likes').innerHTML = responseData;
```

Although, there will be no space between the names, so this would actually be better and just one line of code:

```
document.getElementById('likes').innerHTML = response.likes.data.map(e => e.name).join(', ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `=` hence it will override the `innerHTML` every time.

You should use `+=` which is the equivalent of

```
document.getElementById('likes').innerHTML = document.getElementById('likes').innerHTML + response.likes.data[i].name;
```

In your code it will now be like this

```
for (i = 0; i < response.likes.data.length; i++){      
    document.getElementById('likes').innerHTML += response.likes.data[i].name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time in loop you are replacing the innerhtml value and so only the last element will be displayed in the end. So, Try this,

```
for (i = 0; i < response.likes.data.length; i++){
    var arrVal = document.getElementById('likes').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('likes').innerHTML = arrVal + response.likes.data[i].name;
}
```